# Generic overload for struct does not call correct method

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I have the following two methods:

```
public static T Foo<T> (this ISomething smth, string param) where T : struct { ... }
public static T? Foo<T> (this ISomething smth, string param) where T : struct { ... }
```

When I call the method like so:

```
var result = mySmth.Foo<bool>("Param");
```

I expected `result` to be of type `bool`, but the compiler says it is of type `bool?` - why is that so? How can I force the compiler to call the correct overload?

Comment: I also tried to change the second one to `public static T? Foo<T?> (...)` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you sure that it is possible to have overload methods different only based on return type?

Comment: Maybe not, and the compiler only allows this due to both being extension methods. Is there a good workaround to make it work with nullable AND non-nullable value types?

Comment: You can't have both of those definitions in the same `static class`.

Comment: "*I have the following two methods*" -- no you don't: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AqNDdQ

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That's not true, the compiler doesn't mind. Maybe because both are extension methods.

Comment: @canton7: I'm using an up-to-date VS 2019 with a C#8 project based on .NET 4.8 - it compiles without warnings/errors.

Comment: @D.R. I'm pretty sure that's wrong

Comment: Wow And I'm getting "Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Foo' with the same parameter types"

Comment: I'm getting CS0111 whatever project/framework version  I choose.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem, the file I changed has not been in the same project and it always linked against the pre-compiled library and not the updated file. OK, that mystery is solved. Now: how to fix this method so it can properly return bool/bool? based on the input type?

Comment: This goes back to the original problem with this code and the fact nobody could repro - you cannot overload methods only on return types (and specifically, even if you could, how would the caller indicate which variant they were calling?).

Comment: It could do so via the generic parameter. If the generic parameter is T? then call the T?-version, if  the parameter is T then call the T-version.

Comment: However, Nullable<> is itself also a struct, so again, the compiler would not be able to decide, which overload you want to call. Why don't you just name one overload `FooNullable`, since you expect to be able to tell the compiler, when you want the Nullable result?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? C# cannot resolve methods based on return types. Nor can it resolve methods based on generic constraints. In what way are the two methods different?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an overload (including extensions) vary by only the return type. The best option is to *name* one method with `Nullable`

```
public static T Foo<T> (this ISomething smth, string param) where T : struct { ... }
public static T? NullableFoo<T> (this ISomething smth, string param) where T : struct { ... }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/PPZOhm

Comment: Can you elaborate what's the difference between `Foo<T>` and `Foo<T?>` is if both methods have `where T : struct`? Does the compiler do something different in the second case?